# How to make imageButton' height take 25% of screen sizes in nested linear layout. Android XML landscape layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, landscape

[image]

I want to have to display 9 images. I want the layout to be 3 by 3.

The problem is that the first 3 images in the first row take up two-thirds of screen size.

I have tried to add the nested horizontal linear layout inside a vertical linear layout with wightsum = 3, 1 for each horizontal linear layout. I also added 
**app:layout_heightPercent="25%" app:layout_widthPercent="25%"** and nothing changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/ima6"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/image7"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/image8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/image9"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can make a picture of what exactly you want?
how your images should be look like at the end?

Comment: here is a link to a picture of 3x3 image in landscape layout: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P55zdfZeoqpABPxI5i1cynrHI9F_ST1Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: if this picture is what you want, your code already working!
rows and columns at picture are taking 33% not 25% that you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want get width and height button you can set layout button height and width from this function

```
 private fun calculateImageSize() {
        val windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        //div 3 because want screen (3*3) if u want 25% you can change 4 (25+25+25+25)
        var realWitdh = width / 3 
        var mWidthMenu = realWitdh
        var mHeightMenu = realWidth
    }
```